# How to query MySQL graph data with context point

Tags: php, mysql, graph, flot

I have a working graph on my [website](http://tools.fifaguide.com/player.php?id=1342178905), but the graph data starts and ends within the 24hr timeframe, when really it should start off frame. My query simply looks like:

```
select * where timestamp > 24hrs
```

How can I query all the data within the timeframe, plus the first data point before the timeframe? I can't use a constant value because sometimes the off-screen point is 10 hrs away, and sometimes it's 10 seconds away.

Comment: please provide strucutre of table , some sample data and desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the first data point before the time frame with:

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE timestamp <= 24 ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1
```

If it is possible to have more than one identical timestamp, then this could select one at random - if that's not acceptable then use `ORDER BY timestamp DESC, primary_key` instead.

So you can get what you want via a `UNION`:

```
/* This gets the first item previous to your range limitation */
SELECT
    * FROM yourtable
    WHERE timestamp <= 24 ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1
UNION
/* Your original query */
SELECT
    * FROM yourtable
    WHERE timestamp > 24;
```

I am presuming here (based on your question) that timestamp is an integer, but the above can be tweaked if it is a `DATETIME` column.